# HP 1TB external HDD data recovery

Tags: external-hard-drive, data-recovery

My HP 1TB external HDD stoped working. I was unable to find a service center in my area because it was bought from an online shopping site and some them rejected to service because it was an external HDD and it was out off warranty.

So I planed to check it my self and I opened it and found a Western Digital HDD inside and I connected it to my Windows 7 PC and it asked for initialization and initialize it. But none of my data was found is there any possibility to get my data back.

Comment: Before I did anything, I'd try it with a linux box, since they use a different NTFS implimentation. I'd also try imaging the drive if possible before trying any data recovery

Comment: OK Let's try. @journeyman-geek

Comment: 10 years of data is stored in this HDD.

Comment: In which case doing an image of the entire drive with gddrescue would also be a good idea. And in future, have a duplicate of anything important!

Answer (score 0):

Try Piriform's Recuva - good undelete-ing software. It's free.
www.piriform.com/recuva

Comment: Should i create new partitions, Currently it is not showing any patritions @matan129

Comment: Hm, I misunderstood the question then, I thought you have formatted the drive. Just to be sure, can you post a screenshot of your "My Computer" window?

Comment: Currently it's not the this HDD in "MY Computer".

Comment: Wait. You said that the "data wasn't found" on the drive. How could you know it's not there if it doesn't show up in My Computer? It's not clear to me.

Comment: Also, id the data is very important to you, I strongly recommend you to take the drive to a professional data restoration service. Better safe then sorry, although you can probably restore the data yourself.